# Proper timing for a water bubbling animation

Tags: javascript, svg-animate

I need a water bubbles animation - moving bottom to top.
Here is my way but it's not enough natural.
Obviously - proper timing is problem.
Any help?

```js
var bb = [0, 1, 2];

function bubles() {
  let ran = bb[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  $('.buble').eq(ran).fadeOut().fadeIn();
}

setInterval(function() {
  bubles()
}, 300);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightseagreen;
}

.buble {
  fill: white;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 250" id='svga'>
    <circle class='buble' cx="50" cy="10" r="3"/>
    <circle class='buble' cx="60" cy="20" r="5"/>
    <circle class='buble' cx="50" cy="40" r="7"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried _not_ randomizing the animation? (also: water bubbles get larger as they rise because water pressure decreases)

Comment: Please carefully read my first comment again; your reply does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @ChrisG I need the bubbles to go away so they should be smaller at the top.